# Agora React Native Microphone Permission

Tags: android, ios, react-native, permissions, agora.io

Why does Agora SDK require microphone permission to join a channel even though the channelProfile is set to LiveBroadcasting?

My use case is to have a podcast non interactive, one way only; Broadcaster to Audience, using Agora Voice Call. I don’t want to ask audience for for microphone access unless they are the broadcaster.

Answer (score 0):

By default the SDK sets your role as a "host", you can use the `setClientRole` method to set the user role as "audience" before joining the channel.